# unable to use library build with gobject-introspection in python

Tags: python, c, introspection, gobject

It's my first question on stackoverflow. Before I start I'm sorry for my poor english

I'm currently developing a library "Pocketvox". it's aim is to provide an easy way to use pocketsphinx (voice recognition) on linux system to control it.

The main project is stored here https://github.com/benoitfragit/pocketVox

I've coded in C and I want to give developers an access in Python. So I've generated a .gir and .typelib files. The library name is Pocketvox and every files is present

I tried to load it but if failed:

```
from gi.repository import Pocketvox
```

I've set the GI_TYPELIB_PATH variable in order to point the folder containing typelib file but nothing changed

If someone has knowledge in gobject-introspection C/Python, I need some help to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I found by myself, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not good

Comment: Then you should choose your answer as the correct one.